# Augmented Reality project for virtual dressing room

Tags: kinect, augmented-reality

I'm doing a project on Augmented Reality which the final target is to implement a virtual dressing room. I'm also hoping to use Kinect device to get the motion of the body and map the dress on the body.
  The thing is I don't know how to start and don't know anything about Kinect api. Can you guys help me to get my hands wet on AR with Kinect device.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of resources available on Kinect Development. 
First you need to decide, What you are developing for **Kinect for XBox** or **Kinect for Windows**.
*(Here I'm assuming you are targeting windows)*

Visit [**Official site**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/) for Kinect Developers, here you will find everything - Documentation, SDK and lot of Samples to get you started.

Set up a development environment in 2 steps:

1. Install **Kinect for Windows SDK**.( the download includes APIs and device interfaces.) [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/Develop/Developer-Downloads.aspx)
2. Download and install **Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit**.[Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/Develop/Developer-Downloads.aspx)

Channel9 has a [Kinect Quickstart Series](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart), you can follow these videos and they will show you everything you need to know about Kinect, from setting up development environment to using advance tracking features of Kinect.

**Useful Links:**

- [Step by step instructions for Installing the SDK and Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855354.aspx).
- [Quickstart slides and samples](http://files.ch9.ms/coding4fun/KinectforWindowsSDKV1.zip).
- [Recommended Hardware Configuration for Kinect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131032.aspx#ID4EVC).
- A blog post [Starting to Develop with Kinect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj159883.aspx) to familarize how to use the **Skeleton-tracking capability** of the Kinect.

Answer (score 0):

From the Kinect for Windows website, download the Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx

This includes code samples that will allow you to get started with the API.  There are applications that will introduce you to each of the cameras, how to manage the skeleton as well as how to produce certain effects.  Once you have an understanding of how to work with these elements, you jump into some of the more complex examples in the Toolkit -- the "Green Screen" example should help you in understanding some of the basics of masking elements into the video.

The notion of a virtual dressing room has also been showcased before.  Have a look around YouTube for example videos.

Comment: Thanks..you 2 I was confused but now I know how to start..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general. For the future should be quite specific. However, I recommend you start reading this reference document about augmented reality: [A survey of augmented reality](http://nzdis.otago.ac.nz/projects/projects/berlin/repository/revisions/22/raw/trunk/Master%27s%20Docs/Papers/A%20Survey%20of%20Augmented%20Reality.pdf)

You may also like to review the documents for this search: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=augmented+reality&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=

Then, you should start by reading the tutorials own Kinect. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/Develop/Learn.aspx

Comment: Thanks Lobo this is realy helpful..